# Dart print multiple list item at once

Tags: list, dart

How can I type something like `"print(list[1,4]);"` in Dart?

For example:

```
int main() {
  var products = new List(5);
  products[0] = "Laptop";
  products[1] = "Mouse";
  products[2] = "Keyboard";
  products[3] = "Monitor";
  products[4] = "Microphone";

  print(products[1]); // Mouse
  print(products[1,3]); // I want to see 'Mouse,Monitor'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not directly supported in the SDK but you can easily make a extension on e.g. `List` to add this feature:

```
void main() {
  final products = List<String>(5);
  products[0] = "Laptop";
  products[1] = "Mouse";
  products[2] = "Keyboard";
  products[3] = "Monitor";
  products[4] = "Microphone";

  print(products[1]); // Mouse
  print(products.selectMultiple([1,3]).join(',')); // Mouse,Monitor
}

extension MultiSelectListExtension<E> on List<E> {
  Iterable<E> selectMultiple(Iterable<int> indexes) sync* {
    for (final index in indexes) {
      yield this[index];
    }
  }
}
```

You can't make it so `[1,3]` (as in you own example) would be valid since the `[]` operator does only allow one argument. So instead, we need to make a method which takes our requested indexes as argument.